# parsing a text file in sas

Tags: database, sas

So I have a rather messy text file I'm trying to convert to a sas data set. It looks something like this (though much bigger):

```
0305679  SMITH, JOHN  ARCH05  001  2
ARCH05  005  3
ARCH05  001  7
```

I'm trying to set 5 separate variables (ID, name, job, time, hours) but clearly only 3 of the variables appear after the first line. I tried this:

```
infile "C:\Users\Desktop\jobs.txt" dlm = '  ' dsd missover;
input ID $ name $ job $ time hours;
```

and didn't get the right output, then I tried to parse it

> infile "C:\Users\Desktop\jobs.txt" dlm = '  ' dsd missover; input
>   allData $; id = substr(allData, find(allData,"305")-2, 7);

but I'm still not getting the right output. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm trying now to use .scan() and .substr() to apart the larger data set, how do I subset a single line from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data might not be all that messy; it just might be in a hierarchical format where the first row contains all five variables and subsequent rows contain values for variables 3-5.  In other words, ID and NAME should be retained as you read through the file.

If that is correct (it's a hierarchical layout) this here is a possible solution:

```
data have;
   retain ID NAME;
   informat ID 7. JOB $6. TIME 3. HOURS 1.;
   input @1 test_string $7. @;
   if notdigit(test_string) = 0
      then input @1 ID NAME $12. JOB time hours;
      else input @1 JOB time hours;
   drop test_string;
   datalines;
0305679  SMITH, JOHN  ARCH05  001  2 
ARCH05  005  3 
ARCH05  001  7 
0305680  JONES, MARY  ARCH06  002  4 
ARCH06  005  3 
ARCH07  001  7 
run;
```

The key thing is to really understand how your raw file is organized.  Once you know the rules, using SAS to read it is a snap!

Answer (score 0):

```
 A list input solution could be the following:



data have;
array all(6) $20. ID LNAME FNAME JOB TIME HOURS;
 retain Id Lname Fname;
 drop i;
 input @; 
  nitems = countw(_infile_,', ');  
    if notdigit(scan(_infile_,1)) = 0 then 
     do i = 1 to nitems;
       all(i) = Scan(_infile_,i);
     end;
    else 
     do i = 1 to 3;
    all(i+3) = Scan(_infile_,i);
      if i = 6 then all(i) = all(i)*1;
  end;
datalines;
0305679  SMITH, JOHN  ARCH05  001  2 
ARCH05  005  3 
ARCH05  001  7 
0305680  JONES, MARY  ARCH06  002  4 
ARCH06  005  3 
ARCH07  001  7 
run;

proc print; run;
```